# JSON parse of quote inside double quote

Tags: javascript, json

My value is a string:

```
"['Eitaj', 'Jason Json', 'Eitaj M', "Jason Json's"]"
```

I am trying to parse it using `JSON.parse()`, 
however, I get error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

I find out the the working correct string is:

```
JSON.parse('["Eitaj", "Jason Json", "Eitaj M", "Jason Json\'s"]')
```

Is there any trick I can use other than placing single quotes with double quotes?

Comment: Your first string is invalid.

Comment: @Zenoo `"['Eitaj', 'Jason Json', 'Eitaj M', \"Jason Json's\"]"`, will save string as `"['Eitaj', 'Jason Json', 'Eitaj M', "Jason Json's"]"`

Comment: If you eventually need to extract the individual names (`Eitaj`, `Jason Json`...) the `JSON` object is not going to be of much help because, well, you don't have JSON to begin with. Do you have any control on the data format?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no, it is string coming from other system as I posted.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be JSON? Because it doesn't respect ECMA-404 nor RFC7159 if it's using single-quotes to enclose strings.

Comment: Then you're doomed to have fun with regular expressions and lots of guessing. It isn't a standard format and I presume it isn't even a coherent format. Sorry.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  I think that's python json.dumps result the mixed single quote.. :(

Comment: @Pete JSON.parse can also parse an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether this works for you.

```js
let s = "['Eitaj', 'Jason Json', 'Eitaj M', \"Jason Json's\"]";

let parsed = JSON.parse(s.split(",").map(seg => {
  return seg.replace(new RegExp("'.*'", "g"), function(match) {
    return '"' + match.substring(1, match.length - 1) + '"';
  })
}).join(","));

console.log(parsed);
```

**Update 1**

This will handle flaws of the above snippet which are mentioned in the comments. However there can be still other edge cases which should be handled based on your requirement.

```js
let s = "['Eitaj', 'Jason Json', 'Eitaj M', \"Jason Json's\",\"Test'test'Test\",'Acme, Inc.',\"'Test'\"]";

let parsed = JSON.parse("[" + s.substring(1, s.length - 1).match(new RegExp(`((['\""]).*?(\\2))`, "g")).map(seg => {
  return seg.trim().replace(new RegExp("^'.*'$", "g"), function(match) {
    return '"' + match.substring(1, match.length - 1) + '"';
  })
}).join(",") + "]")

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Careful, this is doomed to fail for values properly enclosed in double-quotes that contain at least two single-quotes, e.g. `"Test'test'Test"`

Comment: ... or names with commas (`'Acme, Inc.'`).

Comment: Updated to handle the flows mentioned. Didn't try to handle other edge cases. There can be many other though.

Comment: @ChathuraWidanage for my constraints it is perfect.